# Access violation when writing two dimensional vectors

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, vector

My program keeps on crashing when `x = 2` and `y = 6` `cellChargeTime[x][y].push_back(0);` Any ideas on how to fix this or what might be causing this crash.

```
vector<int> **cellChargeTime;

cellChargeTime = new vector<int>*[xMax]; //xMax = 40
for (int x=0; x<xMax; x++)
    cellChargeTime[x] = new vector<int> [yMax]; //yMax = 40

for (int x=0; x<xMax; x++){
    for (int y=0; y<yMax; y++){
        for (int i=0; i< numRuns; i++){ //numRuns = 1
            cellChargeTime[x][y].push_back(0); // Crashes at x = 2; y = 6
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [Couldn't reproduce](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/294tgg63sgMYsCQY). Would you mind posting a [Minimal, *Complete*, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Why on earth `vector<int> **cellChargeTime;`??

Comment: @MikeCAT I am not able to reproduce the problem once I compile the above code outside of my main function. Anyway, This is what I get. __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>::deallocate(this=0x485708245c894890, __p=0x8b48000000e0ec81)

Comment: Why not use `vector<vector<int>>` instead and get rid of `new[]` altogether?

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with the code as shown, it works fine (provided you have sufficient `delete[]` statements when you are done using `cellChargeTime`).

However, I would suggest a different approach for memory management:

```
vector<vector<int> > cellChargeTime;

cellChargeTime.resize(xMax);
for (int x=0; x<xMax; x++)
    cellChargeTime[x].resize(yMax);
```

Your loop to populate the vectors does not change at all:

```
for (int x=0; x<xMax; x++){
    for (int y=0; y<yMax; y++){
        for (int i=0; i< numRuns; i++){ //numRuns = 1
            cellChargeTime[x][y].push_back(0);
        }
    }
}
```